# Nginx: Same configuration, one more domain

Tags: nginx, configuration, subdomain

I'm pointing a sub-domain at a specific sub-directory on my server. I am familiar with creating additional configuration files and copying them into sites-enabled/ but let's say I would like to do it inline with one of my existing configuration files. What is the simplest way to point traffic from subdomain.website.com to website.com/subdomain while retaining the same configuration within one file? Here is one of my conf files:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default;
    listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;

    # place for project root
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php;

    # Server host
    server_name subdomain.website.com;

    # logs path
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   # Don't fill up the log file with messages about a missing favicon
   location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
   }

}
```

I do have additional rules but this is just 1 of 3 configuration files. No need to add additional logs either, I would like them all in access.log and error.log.

Comment: Is this a separate vhost config? Be careful with the "default" option, there can be only one. :)

Comment: No vhost or virtual.conf file present. The VirtualHosts section of my nginx.conf is blank. Should I duplicate the server direction and removed the default flag on port?

Comment: I'm assuming you have the include variable in the main nginx.conf which scoops up the *.conf for the vhosts. Simply create a new vhost file that will listen on the publicly available address and omit the default option, test the config and reload nginx.